# How to install python apscheduler on ubuntu as a daemon?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, daemon

I would like to know how do i install python apscheduler on linux Ubuntu as a daemon?
i have read the manual in [here](http://packages.python.org/APScheduler/) but i didn't understand how can i install it as daemon.

I wish to install it like a service and then attach (plug-in) to it all sorts of jobs.

any help?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the daemonic configuration option to true as per the [AP Scheduler Documentation Documentation on python.org](http://packages.python.org/APScheduler/)

Comment: well i have tried this:
<code>sched = Scheduler()
sched.configure({'daemonic':'True'})</code>
and nothing.
I just want to schedule a task every 30 seconds ...

Comment: @Yossi: Disregard if you're already doing this and you only posted the relevant snippet... you need to import the scheduler, then start it - so open with `from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler` and end with `sched.start()`

Answer (score 0):

it uses Scheduler which itself call after some schedule time. you will understand once you will go through scheduler

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me regarding the installation:

```
sudo apt-get -y install python-pip
pip install apscheduler
```

Then set the daemonic configuration option to true when using the apscheduler itself, as mentioned above by  @kathryn.